# How to write data in batches in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I am writing a partitioned dataframe to csv using the following code:

```
df.write \
.option("header",True) \
.partitionBy("state")\
.mode("overwrite") \
.option("encoding",'utf-8')\
.format("csv") \
.save("filepath")
```

The problem is the size of the overall data is 100's of GB's and my local system does not have that much storage space.

How do I write the data in batches such that after the first batch is written in CSV, there is a delay of some time, so that I can transfer the CSV file to another system and delete it from the original path to clear storage space for the next file.

And then the code should run again and create another CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the time module if you want to pause

```
import time #its inbuilt so no need to 'pip install time'

time.sleep(1)#this will pause for 1 second
time.sleep(120)#this will pause for 2 mins
```